# Change ftp folder permission via command line

Tags: windows, ftp, cmd

I'm using windows command line [MS FTP](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/MSFTP.htm) for ftp access. However I furthermore must change folder permission via command line as well. I tried CACLS command, alas that doesn't work in open ftp commmand window. Any hint's appreciated

Comment: This question may be better suited for superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change permissions if you use a good GUI client.

Give the following a try and let us know if it works for you!

- [Filezilla](http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/)
- [FTP Commander](http://www.internet-soft.com/ftpcomm.htm)

Answer (score 0):

FTP is an Internet standard designed by people who work together to a common goal. CACLS is a pile of Microsoft-invented stuff that FTP knows nothing about so that is not going to work unless someone implements a QUOTE command to pass it through. The nearest you can get to changing permissions is with the CHMOD command.